# bash trap not working when script is sourced

Tags: bash

sorry I cannot figure out what is wrong with the following. When I hit ctrl-c in a script the trap works, but does not when the script is source executed.

Example (test2.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

ctrl_c()
{                                                 
  echo "user canceled."                                    
}                                                          

trap ctrl_c INT

sleep 500

trap - INT
```

The following happens:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ./test2
^Cuser canceled.

[root@localhost ~]# . test2
^C
```

This is RHEL 7, Bash 4.2, but the same problem is also happening in other Linux distributions and also Bash 4.4.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: A second CTRL & C after sourcing fires the trap function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I solved my problem. Maybe it's not the best or most elegant way but it seems to work just fine.

The trick is to run the procedure in a background task (child process), then wait for the process to finish. While the background process ($!) is running, trap INT will work and do the cleanup. Since I need to source some commands I write them into a file and then source execute the files in the main script. These file, however, are cleaned upon Ctrl-C and hence the script ends.

For example:

```
# scan.sh

scan.sh, not sourced. Aborting...

# source scan.sh

 [|] Working...^C
scan.sh: waiting for process 22390 to terminate...
scan.sh: user canceled.
[1]+  Interrupt               doit $f_menu $f_alias
```

I did not find a working solution to eliminate the "Interrupted" message, but that's not really a concern.

```
#!/bin/bash
....
# Preliminary options and environment. 
save_monitor=$(set +o | grep -w monitor)
set +o monitor # Turn off monitor mode.
save_history=$(set +o | grep -w history)
set +o history # Turn off command line history.
save_extglob=$(shopt -p extglob)
shopt -s extglob
f_menu=/tmp/1_$$
f_alias=/tmp/2_$$ 
iam=scan.sh                                        

cleanup()
{ # Requires $1 (f_menu) $2 (f_alias) args.
  # Restore shell the previous shell environment.  
  unset i f_pid f_menu f_alias aver iam list aname line sourced
  unset spinner doit cleanup ctrl_c
  trap - INT
  \rm -f $1 $2 # Don't use rm alias.
  eval "$save_extglob"
  eval "$save_monitor"
  eval "$save_history"
  unset save_extglob save_history save_monitor
}
 
# Exit if the script was not sourced.
$(return >/dev/null 2>&1) && sourced=1 || unset sourced
[[ "$sourced" ]] || { echo; echo "$iam, not sourced. Aborting..."; exit 1; } 

ctrl_c()
{ # Requried: f_pid f_quit
  # Optional: f_menu $f_alias
  kill -TERM $f_pid
  while (( f_pid )); do
    echo; echo "$iam: waiting for process $f_pid to terminate..."
    sleep 2
    [[ $(kill -0 $f_pid 2>&-) ]] || f_pid=
  done
  echo "$iam: user canceled."
  cleanup $f_menu $f_alias
}

trap ctrl_c INT

spinner()
{ 
  # Optional: $1
  local disp
  disp='|/-\'
  while kill -0 $! 2>&-; do
    printf " [%c] %s..." "$disp" "$1"
    disp=${disp#?}${disp%%???}
    sleep .1
    printf "\r"
  done
}

doit()
{ 
  # Requires $1 (f_menu) $2 (f_alias) args. 
 
  .....

}

echo
doit $f_menu $f_alias &
f_pid=$!; spinner "Working"; wait $f_pid

# Following will no longer work after user hit control-c.
source $f_alias 2>&-
cleanup $f_menu $f_alias 2>&-

# end
```

Comment: Just spawn a subshell and do all the work in the subshell, and execute cleanup on `EXIT`. Why would you want to do `doit` in the current execution environment? Produce an output from a subshell that would change the current environment, and `eval` it, other then that do everything in a subshell.

Comment: You mean running ( doit ) in parenthesis as opposed to doit & as a background job? I tried that before, but had more trouble with canceling and cleanup, and obtaining process feedback, etc.. I'm not just cleaning on exit but also running a "progress spinner" and support ctrl-c while the process works in the background. It can perhaps be done if I invest more time, but I don't see the advantage. The original script is much more complex than shown here for the purpose of demonstrating a particular problem.

Comment: I mean instead of `eval "$save_extglob:,,,,` part.  If the user has it's own `doit(){ echo user function; }` and then does `. ./your_script.sh`, he's function will be overwritten. You are changing the environment, and a lot, and defining functions and setting variables - spaghetti code. Instead, do your work in a subshell, so they do not affect environment.

Comment: I suppose I did not want to rewrite larger portions of the script that started out to be a sourced script at the expense of more complex process management logic. Spaghetti was on the menu that day. Thanks for the tip, I keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall that interactive shells (which is where you're doing the trap because you're sourcing it rather than running it asynchronously) have special handling for `SIGINT`. They capture it themselves so that process control calls can be interrupted.

I suspect that's getting in the way of what you're trying to do.

---

UPDATE: Just had a look at the `bash` man-page, the `SIGNALS` section there is a little vague but it *does* seem to confirm my recollection re the special handling in interactive shells.

> **SIGNALS**
>
> When `bash` is interactive, in the absence of any traps, it ignores `SIGTERM` (so that `kill 0` does not kill an interactive shell), and `SIGINT` is caught and handled (so that the `wait` builtin is interruptible). In all cases, `bash` ignores `SIGQUIT`.

Comment: I tried the read command instead of sleep an there it works also when the script is sourced. So sleep is the issue, intercepting trap?

Comment: I did some more tests and trap INT works interactively at the command prompt, but only when there is no process executing. So I guess that means one cannot use trap INT while a sourced script is executing.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is of course more complex than printing a message. I need to source a script to define some aliases and wish to cleanup after ctrl-c. I can run a function in the background and trap INT works for the duration of the background task. But I cannot abort the script with exit when sourced.  And when sourced it won't trap INT unless running a background task. Catch 22. I'll have see if I can do what I need to in a background task. Then on trap INT kill the background job and do the cleanup.

Comment: `define some aliases and wish to cleanup after ctrl-c` Then do not ask XY questions. Do a new question, state what you want to do and why.